# CSR custom colum not available in CurrentItem

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, client-side-rendering

I created a new sharepoint content type with created custom columns, then created a new task list. I made my content type as default. If I try to get the value of my created columns (text) I get an undefined (of course I use the internal name of the column).

Do I get only the value of default sharepoint columns? Or am I missing something?

```
(function (){
    //init
    var inCtx = {};
    var mfield = {};
    inCtx.Templates = {};

    inCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverride;

    inCtx.Templates.Header = "<div>";
    inCtx.Templates.Footer = "</div>";

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(inCtx);

    function ItemOverride(itemCtx){
        var result = "";
        result += "<h4>";
        result += itemCtx.CurrentItem.Title + " ";
        result += itemCtx.CurrentItem["MYCOLUMN"];
        result += "</h4>";

        return result;
    }

})();
```

I added console.log(itemCtx.CurrentItem) to my function:

```
AssignedTo:Array[1]
Checkmark:"Nein"
ContentType:"MY CONTENT TYPE"
ContentTypeId:"0x010800B190D14F1764B34B90CEC6190DEBEA2D00CAA91C9504256348A9CD224C2E078360"
Created_x0020_Date.ifnew:"1"
DueDate:"19.08.2016"
DueDate.FriendlyDisplay:"1|1|7|Freitag"
FSObjType:"0"
FileLeafRef:"1_.000"
FileRef:"/sites/mr_demo/Lists/Zieleliste/1_.000"
File_x0020_Type:""
File_x0020_Type.mapapp:""
HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon:""
HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapico:"icgen.gif"
ID:"1"
PercentComplete:"0 %"
PercentComplete.:"0"
PermMask:"0x7fffffffffffffff"
Title:"Task 1"
firstRow:true
outlineLevel:"1"
__proto__:Object
```

Comment: Custom column that you need to display, Is that in the view ?

Comment: Yes it is in the view and i need to display it.

Comment: add a ``console.log(itemCtx)`` inside the function and see what you get in the F12 console

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I get a object with a lot of information. Should I look for something specific?

Comment: Check for itemCtx‌​.CurrentItem

Comment: @Ravindra Done, updated my question with the result of console.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

I had to click Edit Page -> Edit Webpart. There I changed the view from "< Current View >" explicit to the View - even if it was the same.

Now I can get my stuff done, thx @all!